# Calling overloaded method in .net class does not work

Tags: php, .net, overloading

When trying to execute an overloaded method of a .net class I always get the error that the number of parameters is incorrect.

.net code :

```
    public bool AddStock(double AWidth, double AHeight, int aCount)
    {
      return this.Manager.(AWidth, AHeight, aCount, string.Empty, 0);
    }

    public bool AddStock(double AWidth, double AHeight, int aCount, string aID)
    {
      return this.Manager.(AWidth, AHeight, aCount, aID, 0);
    }

    public bool AddStock(double AWidth, double AHeight)
    {
      return this.AddStock(AWidth, AHeight, 1);
    }
```

In PHP :

This works :

```
$e->AddStock(2440, 1220, 1);
```

This doesn't :

```
$e->AddStock(2440, 1220, 1, 'Test');
```

Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Error [0x8002000e] Invalid number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of Googling I found that overloaded methods are accessible if you add an underscore and a number.

The solution was to

```
$e->AddStock_3(2440, 1220, 1, 'Test');
```